# How to create 2 foreign keys with Laravel migration

Tags: laravel-5, foreign-keys, database-migration

I have letter's model and this model has 2 foreign keys from attachments and contacts

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('letters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('attachment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
        $table->foreign('attachment_id')->references('id')->on('attachments');
    });
}
```

This is what I have tried so far. But when I type artisan migration SQL I receive the following error

General error: 1005 Can't create table `ss`.`#sql-1064_4a` (errno: 150 "Foreign
  key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `letters` add constraint `letters_attach

  ment_id_foreign` foreign key (`attachment_id`) references `attachments` (`id`))

Comment: could you show migrations for `contacts` and `attachments` tables?

Answer (score 1):

first create table rows then add forgin keys.

```
   Schema::create('letters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('attachment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
       Schema::table('letters', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
        $table->foreign('attachment_id')->references('id')->on('attachments');
        });
```

i guess this will work